# Concept of "guessed ID" in Authenticated Identity-Based Encryption

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, identity-based-encryption

In [Authenticated Identity-Based Encryption by Ben Lynn](https://eprint.iacr.org/2002/072.pdf), in Proof of Integrity (section 4.3) and Proof of Security (section 4.4), I cannot grab the concept of "guessed ID" . Because encryption differs according to "guessed ID", I am unable to know how it works.

Is there anyone who can help explain this term and how it affects the proof?

Comment: Please take a look at my edits. Try and include links and concrete references within your question. This saves us a lot of work and increases your chance of getting good answers. I've narrowed down your last question as the proofs are 3 pages in size; we cannot be expected to break that down even if we knew what you aren't able to grab.

Answer (score 1):

"Guessed ID" means ID that the oracle guesses the attacker algorithm $A$ will attack.

Comment: It could well be that this is the correct answer. But currently it's not a very clear sentence, nor does it explain why this is so or reference any part of the linked paper. In other words, could you expand this answer a bit?